# Antialiased GLSL impostors

Tags: glsl, antialiasing

If you draw a sphere using an impostor based ray-tracing approach as described for example here

http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tutorial%2013.html

you typically draw a quad and then use 'discard' to skip pixels that have a distance from the quad center larger than the sphere radius.

When you turn on anti-aliasing, GLSL will anti-alias the border of the primitive you draw - in this case the quad - but not the border between the drawn and discarded pixels.

I have attached two screen shots displaying the sphere and a blow-up of its border. Except for the top-most pixels, that lie on the quad border, clearly the sphere border has not been anti-aliased.

[image: Impostor based sphere]
[image: Sphere border zoom-in]

Is there any trick I can use to make the impostor spheres have a nice anti-aliased border?

Best regard,

Mads

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just discarding the pixel, set your sphere to have inner and outer radius.
Everything inside the inner radius is fully opaque, everything outside the outer radius is discarded, and anything in between is linearly interpolated between 0 and 1 alpha values.

```
float alpha = (position - inner) / (outer - inner);
```

Comment: You are also going to want blending for this to do anything. Frankly, you could probably just implement this in the shader itself... `output = mix (<black>, <color>, alpha)`.

Comment: Thanks. Problem is that typically I have several spheres - so I need to mix with current frag color. So mixing with black will only work when I only have a single sphere. Instead I tried with blending, but in that case I need all the spheres to be drawn back to front with respect to their view-space Z-coordinate. Hmm...

Answer (score 1):

Kneejerk reaction would be to multisample for yourself: render to a texture that is e.g. four times as large as your actual output, then ensure you generate mip maps and render from that texture back onto your screen.

Alternatively do that directly in your shader and let OpenGL continue worrying about geometry edges: sample four rays per pixel and average them.